# Passing array type of data through postman

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, postman

I have a simple post method in express.

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.post('/addPerson',function(req,res){
    const name = req.body.name;
    const age = req.body.age;
    const address = req.body.address;

    console.log(address);
});
```

I am trying to input data through postman. I want the address field to be an array of objects,like so-

address = [{name:'apple,color:'red'}]

but all the fields passed through postman are strings,so it becomes like this -

address = '[{name:'apple,color:'red'}]'

How can I get an array from this? I am using xxx-www-form-urlencoded method.

Comment: try 
```raw -> JSON``` instead of ```xxx-www-form-urlencoded```

Comment: I tried sending it like this by selecting raw. 
{
 name:"Raj",
 age:67
}

It just returns {} on req.body.

Comment: you have to select ```JSON``` also after selecting ```raw```. ```raw``` sends ```Text``` by default.

Comment: Tried. Same thing. Empty object in req.body.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass array data to postman call in `Body > raw` and then select `JSON` from dropdown at end [image]

Comment: I get an empty object in req.body if I do anything other than x-www-form-urlencoded. I think this is because I use **app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));**

Comment: what is your express version? can you check that in package.json file?

Comment: Express version is 4.17.1

Comment: just comment out the body parser package and check again. i am using 4.16.0 version and works for me without body-parser package.

Comment: even i tried with body-parser package and works find for me , this is what i get in console

{
  name: 'abc',
  age: 25,
  address: [
    { name: 'apple', color: 'red' },
    { name: 'apple', color: 'red' },
    { name: 'apple', color: 'red' }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

Apparently,the line -

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

was preventing the app from using a raw json input through postman. So,I had to add a new line -

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

This lets us use postman's raw json input format instead of x-www-form-urlencoded.

**Note:-This overwrites the effect of urlencoded and you can only use one. Either urlencoded or json.**